# "Exception in Tkinder callback Traceback" App de escritorio con SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

Estoy haciendo una sencilla app de escritorio con Tkinter y SQLite, es una app sencilla de un curso de internet usando CRUD y de repente me salto este error aun cuando mi código es exactamente igual al del curso

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>           Traceback (most recent call last):
>             File "C:\Users\Mihor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 1705, in **call**
>               return self.func(*args)
>             File "D:\Documentos\Programacion\Python\tkinder-products-app\index.py",
>   line 72, in add_product
>               self.get_products()
>             File "D:\Documentos\Programacion\Python\tkinder-products-app\index.py",
>   line 53, in get_products
>               self.three.delete(element)
>           AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'three

Este es mi codigo

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

import sqlite3

class Product:

    # Connection dir property
    db_name = 'database.db'

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('Products application')

        # Creating a Frame Container
        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Register a new product')
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady= 20)

        # Name input
        Label(frame, text = 'Name: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.name = Entry(frame)
        self.name.focus()
        self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        # Price input
        Label(frame, text = 'Price: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.price = Entry(frame)
        self.price.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        # Button add product
        ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Save Product', command = self.add_product).grid(row = 3, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

        # Table
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height = 10, columns = 2)
        self.tree.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Name', anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#1', text = 'Price', anchor = CENTER)

        # Filling the rows
        self.get_products()

    def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return result

    def get_products(self):
        # Cleanning table
        records = self.tree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.three.delete(element)
        # Quering data
        query = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY name DESC' 
        db_rows = self.run_query(query)
        # Filling data
        for row in db_rows: 
            self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[1], values = row[2])

    def validation(self):
        return len(self.name.get()) != 0 and len(self.price.get()) != 0

    def add_product(self):
        if self.validation():
            query = 'INSERT INTO product VALUES(NULL, ?, ?)'
            parameters = (self.name.get(), self.price.get())
            self.run_query(query, parameters)
            print('Data Saved')
        else:
            print('Name and Price is required')   
        self.get_products()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    application = Product(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola TensaSangetsu1254, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. El error es bastante claro, tu objeto de la clase `Product` no tiene el atributo `three` definido (`self.three`) en el momento de llamar al método de instancia `get_products`. Me temo que es imposible ayudarte sin ver el código y ver dónde defines `self.three` si es que lo haces. Por favor agrega el código o al menos un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: Ya esta agregado amigo

Comment: Es un typo, el atributo  es `tree` no `three`, cambia `self.three.delete(element)` en `get_product` por `self.tree.delete(element)`.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, esto fue un dolor de cabeza.

Comment: De nada, suele pasar con los typo, repasas el código cuarenta veces y no lo ves... :( Voy a votar para el cierre de la pregunta, dado que es un error tipográfico no será de ayuda para otros usuarios. Saludos.